# Error in Dojo with highCharts showLoading option

Tags: dojo, highcharts

I get this error in the console when I executed this http://jsfiddle.net/ikercrg/FSfR2/3/:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method '_getStyle'

The error happens because of these lines:

```
chart.showLoading();
...
chart.hideLoading();
```

And obviously nothing happen with this 'loading' option.

How can I solve this problem and make this 'loading' works correctly?

Comment: Looks like a bug in standalone version, reported [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2268).

Comment: I see the bug solved. Is it now in production or must I wait for the Highcharts next version?

Comment: You can wait for 3.0.6 version, or download http://github.highcharts.com/master/highcharts.js - but this may contain another issues which aren't resolved.

Comment: Thanks, and is it any data for the 3.0.6 version release?

Comment: No strict date - should be ready within a few weeks.